# Loop to read fixed record number of records at a time from a dataset until all the records are read

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

I'm working in the sales department of a company and every month we have some products which sales revenue are negative. My job is to extract those products ID to analyse them. I use WPS which uses SAS language. So I need first to extract the products ID with a proc sql (for exemple in february 9680 products).
And in a second step I use those IDs in a proc sql to get extra information on those product like their price, date etc...

The problem is that in WPS there is a limitation of 3000 observations than can be read extracted in a proc sql statement.
So I need to do a loop that counts the number of IDs in a month and then extract information of the 3000 first IDs which it appends with the following IDs and append again and again until I get all 9680 IDs with the extra information they go along.

My code is:

```
PROC SQL;  
    CREATE TABLE Febsales.NB_IDs AS 
    SELECT /* COUNT of Number of products  */
        (COUNT(t1.ID)) AS NB_ID
FROM ID_prod t1
WHERE t1.ID_sales_revenue < 0;
QUIT;
```

The rest I don't know how to do it.

My idea is to tell sas to:

```
do i=1 to='&NB_ID' by=3000
```

And then extract with the following code:

```
%TeradataOpen (Lib=  Revenue AF Socle ODS,dataout=af0215_liste1)
SELECT
    OD_prod.pd_ID,
    OD_prod.pd_line ,
    OD_prod.pd_serie ,
    OD_prod.pd_manu,
    OD_prod.pd_cust_ID,
    OD_prod.pd_price,
    OD_prod.pd_amount,
    OD_prod.pd_cost,
    OD_prod.pd_buyer,
    OD_prod.pd_mkt_share,
    OD_prod.pd_gross,
    OD_prod.pd_marketor,
    sum(OD_prod.pd_mkt_share) as tot_share,
    sum(OD_prod.pd_GROss) as tot_rev,
    OD_prod.DAT_prod as prod,
FROM
    OD_prod,
    OD_ manufact
WHERE .....
```

And then a:

```
proc append
```

Comment: Is the limit only in the initial connection to the external database, or is it always limited to 3000 records in any SQL statement?  And how are you reading them - in the above you neither use a CONNECT TO nor a fully qualified libname/table name, so it's unclear - is the `%TeradataOpen` performing a `connect to teradata`?  Is the SQL you list above really pass-through syntax?

Comment: Also - is it possible in WPS to use a data step to read the data (like it would be in SAS)?

Comment: 3000 records seems like an artificial limit to me. Where is this limit being configured? Can't you just change that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below

- `Num` is the total number of observation in the source dataset, you are doing that in the first step
- `Chunk` is the number of observations you want to read at a time, 3000
  in your case.

Below snippet of code doing the following things:

- is generating the `starting`(like 1, 3001, 6001 etc) and `ending`(3000,6000,9000 etc) position of records to read in each loop
- counting the number of loops required to read all the records
- reading the above three in a macro variable

---

```
 %let num=10000;
    %let chunk=3000;

    data _NULL_;
    length startp $200. endp $200.;
    Numofloop=int(&num./&chunk.);

    if _N_=1 then do; startp=1; endp=&chunk.; end;

    do i=1 to Numofloop-1;
    sp=i*&chunk + 1;
    ep=(i+1)*&chunk.;

    if i=Numofloop-1 then ep=&num.;

    startp=catx(",",startp,sp);
    endp=catx(",",endp,ep);

    put _ALL_;
    output;
    call symput("startp",startp);
    call symput("endp",endp);
    call symput("loop",Numofloop);
    end;

    run;
```

---

In this step using the `loop` and the `starting` and `ending positions`, 3000 records are being read in each step in the `temp` dataset and is being appended in the `alldata` dataset.

```
    %macro read;

    %do i=1 %to &loop.;

    %let sp=%sysfunc(scan("&startp.",&i.,","));
    %let ep=%sysfunc(scan("&endp.",&i.,","));

    data temp;
    set test(firstobs=&sp. obs=&ep.);
    run;

    proc append base=alldata data=temp force;
    run;

    %end;
    %mend;

    %read;
```

This may not be the exact solution of your question but of course you can build your  code using this

Comment: Thank you very much I'm out of office, I will adapt it on monday and let you know! Nice WE

Comment: Hello NEOmen If I'm right this part of the code data temp; set test(firstobs=&sp. obs=&ep.); run; proc append base=alldata data=temp force; run;

Comment: I've posted above what I did @NEOmen

Answer (score 0):

1. Create list of IDs
2. Split them into 3000 ID groups
3. Build an SQL view to get the supplemental data for each group
4. Concatenate all the views together

```
%LET LIMIT = 3000 ;
/* Get list of IDs */
proc sql ;
  create table idlist as
  select distinct ID
  from id_prod
  where ID_SALES_REVENUE < 0
  order by ID ;
quit ;

/* Assign GROUP number to each set of &LIMIT ID's */
data idlist2 ;
  set idlist ;
  N = _n_ ;
  GROUP = floor(N / &LIMIT) + 1;
run ;

/* Get number of groups */
proc sql ;
  select max(GROUP) into :GRP_CNT from idlist2 ;
quit ;

%MACRO BUILD_VIEWS ;
  /* Build view1-view<n> for each group of &LIMIT ID's */
  proc sql ;
    %DO G = 1 %TO &GRP_CNT ;

    create view pd_view&G as
    select ...
    from od_prod, od_manufact
    where ...
      and pd_id in(select ID from idlist2 where GROUP = &G) ;

    %END ;
  quit ;
%MEND ;
%BUILD_VIEWS ;

/* Now read from each view into 1 dataset */
data master ;
  set pd_view1-pd_view&GRP_CNT ;
run ;
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. I'm out of office now but Monday I will adapt it and run it and let you know. Thank you so much for spending time on it.

Comment: Hello,@ChrisJ, Sorry for for the time I took to answer you I had another prior issue to solve but I still got to fix this one of issue. I tried to adapt your code and everything is fine until I get into the Build view macro. I get an error when I type 
 `(select ID from idlist2 where GROUP = &G);` . 
BTW GROUP is an SQL keyword so I changed it in 
`subsets = floor(N / &LIMIT) + 1; ... 
select max(Subsets) into :GRP_CNT from idlist2 ...`
and then typed`(select ID from idlist2 where Subsets = &G);` 
The log says 
`DATABASE error: No such member 3807: Object 'idlist2' does not exist.`

Comment: If you're getting a database error, that seems to imply you're doing a pass-through query, and as such `idlist2` is not within your database, it's in SAS. Either upload `idlist2` into your DB, or run it all in SAS rather than as a pass-thru query.